# Setting the Encryption Key in Laravel results to logout

Tags: php, encryption, laravel, mcrypt

i need the  key that  will be used for subsequent `Crypt::encrypt()` and `Crypt::decrypt()` calls **but only in the current request.**

```
    Crypt::setKey('1');
    $pin_code   = Crypt::encrypt($pin_codes[$key]);
```

**// it do the encryption and then automatically log out**

what could be the issue?

Comment: Its probably resulting in a different encryption setting, and meaning your session is becoming invalid I would guess...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out

There's only three places Laravel uses the Crypt package.

1. Caches. Specifically if you're using the Database Cache driver then values placed in the cache are encrypted prior to saving and decrypted when loaded.
2. Cookies. Cookie values are always sent to the user encrypted. When the request loads, all cookie values are decrypted.
3. Queues. Specifically if you're using the iron queue driver then values are stored in the queue encrypted and decrypted once retrieved.

**Because of point no 2 ... we will be logged out of the system**

so better to reset key to original

```
Crypt::setKey('1'); 
$pin_code   = Crypt::encrypt($pin_codes[$key]);
Crypt::setKey(Config::get('app.key'));//reset to original after job is done
```